# Mixing Audio elements into one stream destination for use with MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

MediaRecorder only lets you record media of one type per track. So I'm using JQuery to get a list off all audio elements and connect them to the same audio context destination in order to mix all the audio tracks into one audio stream to later be recorded by MediaRecorder. What I have so far works but only captures the first track and none of the others.

Any idea why only one track comes through?

my code:

```
function gettracks(stream){
    var i = 0;
    var audioTrack ;
    var audioctx = new AudioContext();
    var SourceNode = [];
    var  dest = audioctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
    $('audio').each( function() {

    //the audio element id
    var afid = $(this).attr('id');

    var audio = $('#'+afid)[0];
    console.log('audio id '+ afid+' Audio= '+audio);
    SourceNode[i] = audioctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);

    //dont forget to connect the wires!
    SourceNode[i].connect(audioctx.destination);
    SourceNode[i].connect(dest);


      audioTrack = dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    stream.addTrack(audioTrack);
    i++;
    });
    }


//from a mousedown event I call
stream = canvas.captureStream();
video.srcObject = stream;

gettracks(stream);
startRecording()
    function startRecording() {
          recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: 'video/webm'
      });
      recorder.start();
    }
```

Comment: What is the `stream` parameter? Can you add the calling code?

Comment: Hi, thanks I updated the post will calling code. The video capture works too. but only audio track in it.

Comment: I think the `SourceNode[i].connect(audioctx.destination);` line shouldn't be there. And maybe do `stream.addTrack(dest.stream.getAudioTracks()[0])` after the loop instead of inside it.

Comment: Still only one track comes through. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you create a gain node and connect your source nodes to that:

```
var gain = audioctx.createGain();
gain.connect(dest);
```

and in the loop

```
SourceNode[i].connect(gain);
```

Then your sources flow into a single gain node, which flows to the your destination.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```js
var ac = new AudioContext();
var mediaStreamDestination = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(ac);
document.querySelectorAll("audio").forEach((e) => {
  var mediaElementSource = new MediaElementAudioSourceNode(ac, { mediaElement: e });
  mediaElementSource.connect(mediaStreamDestination);
});
console.log(mediaStreamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]); // give this to MediaRecorder
```

Breaking down what the above does:

- `var ac = new AudioContext();`: create an `AudioContext`, to be able to route audio to something else than the default audio output.
- `var mediaStreamDestination = new MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode(ac);` from this `AudioContext`, get a special type of `DestinationNode`, that, instead of send the output of the `AudioContext` to the audio output device, sends it to a `MediaStream` that holds a single track of audio.
- `document.querySelectorAll("audio").forEach((e) => {`, get all the `<audio>` elements, and iterate over them.
- `var mediaElementSource = new MediaElementAudioSourceNode(ac, { mediaElement: e });`, for each of those media element, capture its output and route it to the `AudioContext`. This gives you an `AudioNode`.
- `mediaElementSource.connect(mediaStreamDestination);`, connect our `AudioNode` that has the output of the media element, connect it to our destination that goes to a `MediaStream`.
- `mediaStreamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0]` get the first audio `MediaStreamTrack` from this `MediaStream`. It has only one anyways.

Now, I suppose you can do something like `stream.addTrack(mediaStreamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0])`, passing in the audio track above.

Comment: Thanks for all the detail I really appreciate your help. For some reason I still only get one track coming through.  The track that does come through is at a lower volume than it should be. It's almost as if it is being clobbered but there is no trace of any other sounds. This may be a little far fetched but do you know if it is possible to put each track on it's own channel in the stream?

Comment: It's certainly possible. For this, you want a [ChannelMergerNode](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#channelmergernode), and then use the [this form](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audionode-connect) of `AudioNode.connect`, changing the last argument to connect to the right input of the `ChannelMergerNode`.